# PowerShell in error using GetEventLog CmdLet

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to run a PowerShell script and try to filter by the message.

```
param($server, $message)
Try
{
    Invoke-Command -computername $server {Get-Eventlog -logname application -source "source" -message $message | Format-List}
}
Catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString()
}
```

I am trying to run the script with the following parameters:

```
GetEventLog.ps1 "SERVERNAME" "TEXT_TO_FIND"
```

> cannot validate an argument on parameter 'Message'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or
>   empty and then try the command again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-EventLog], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetEventLogCommand

For some reason it handles the $server parameter fine, but if complains about the $message variable.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Get-EventLog is so slow!!. I ended using this..


   Get-WinEvent -computername $server -FilterHashTable @{LogName='application';providername=$provider} | Where-Object {$_.Message -match $message -And $_.TimeCreated -ge $after -And $_.TimeCreated -le $before}

Answer (score 3):

You can get the events without Invoke-Command:

```
Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName application -source "source" -message $message
```

In case the command generates an error you won't be able to catch it since it probably will not be a terminating error. To make the error terminating, use the ErrorAction parameter:

```
   Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName application -ErrorAction Stop ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
Invoke-Command -computername $server {Get-Eventlog -logname application -source "source" -message $args[0] | Format-List} -ArgumentList $message
```

Comment: This is not the right solution as that of @ShayLevy but anyway it solves the error you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass $message as an argument using the -ArgumentList parameter. Check out example 9 of the man page:

*[Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd347578(v=technet.10))*

```
invoke-command -computername server01 -scriptblock {param($log, $num) get-eventlog -logname $log -newest $num} -ArgumentList $MWFO_Log, 10
```

Comment: Have to try this but definitely not as clear and simple as Shay Levy answer. Why do I need to use scriptblock?. I guess if i dont use the invoke-command then i wouldn't need this approach. :)

Comment: @Maverick Yep, it just so happens the Get-EventLog cmdlet supports remote execution already so no need to use Invoke-Command.